# Change color of text in collapsed dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Where can I change color of text in collapsed dropdown? For some reason there's different background and text colors in my dropdown menu when its collapsed.

When not collapsed I can change it with:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #000;
}
```

But when collapsed it won't change. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

When the dropdown is open, it will have the `open` class added to the parent dropdown element.  You can use that to selectively style a closed / open dropdown.

For example, take the following **HTML**:

```html
<div class="dropdown">

    <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

We can add a color property to the dropdown and then change the color property when open using the following **CSS**: *(*you might have to use `!important` if the button is styled*)

```css
.dropdown > button {
    color: yellow;
}
.dropdown.open > button {
    color: orange;
}
```

## [Working Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/6gNER/)

Which will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

If you only wanted to change the style while closed you could use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class selector like this:

```css
.dropdown:not(.open) > button {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in bootstrap which overwrites collapsed navigation colors with the navbar-default ones (see bootstraps navbar.less line 468).

In order to fix it add the following less code after importing bootstrap to your project:

```
@media (max-width: @grid-float-breakpoint-max) {

 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
   > li > a {
     color: @dropdown-link-color;
     &:hover,
     &:focus {
       color: @dropdown-link-hover-color;
       background-color: @dropdown-link-hover-bg;
     }
   }
   > .active > a {
     &,
     &:hover,
     &:focus {
       color: @dropdown-link-active-color;
       background-color: @dropdown-link-active-bg;
     }
   }
 }

}
```